# Summary information column in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT sds.district_id,detail.year, detail.race, SUM(count)
FROM school_data_race_ethnicity_raw as detail
INNER JOIN school_data_schools as sds USING (school_id)
GROUP BY district_id, year, race
```

Sample Result set:

```
| 68080104    | 2009 | Multiracial     |          0 |
| 68080104    | 2009 | White           |        847 |
| 68080104    | 2010 | American Indian |          1 |
| 68080104    | 2010 | Asian           |          4 |
| 68080104    | 2010 | Black           |         17 |
| 68080104    | 2010 | Hispanic        |          4 |
| 68080104    | 2010 | Multiracial     |          2 |
| 68080104    | 2010 | White           |        823 |
| 68080104    | 2011 | American Indian |          4 |
| 68080104    | 2011 | Asian           |          4 |
| 68080104    | 2011 | Black           |          9 |
| 68080104    | 2011 | Hispanic        |         10 |
| 68080104    | 2011 | Multiracial     |         24 |
| 68080104    | 2011 | White           |        767 |
+-------------+------+-----------------+------------+
```

I want to add a 5th column called total which displays a summation of the total population of for a given year and district. For example if I was in district 68080104 in 2011, the total would be (4+4+9+10+24+767). I need this as another column in this query. It also needs to be fast. (Under 10 seconds). I am struggling on how to do this and not compromise speed and data.

Comment: check my solution below, you need to create a separate query to count the values and later join it with the original one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a separate query for that and join it with the original one. Try this,

```
SELECT a.*, b.totalCount
FROM
    (
        SELECT sds.district_id,detail.year, detail.race, SUM(count)
        FROM    school_data_race_ethnicity_raw as detail
                    INNER JOIN school_data_schools as sds 
                        USING (school_id)
        GROUP BY district_id, year, race
    )   a INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT sds.district_id,detail.year, SUM(count) totalCount
        FROM    school_data_race_ethnicity_raw as detail
                    INNER JOIN school_data_schools as sds 
                        USING (school_id)
        GROUP BY district_id, year
    )   b ON a.district_id = b.district_id AND
            a.year = b.year
```

Answer (score 1):

Use WITH ROLLUP

```
SELECT sds.district_id,detail.year, detail.race, SUM(count)
FROM school_data_race_ethnicity_raw as detail
INNER JOIN school_data_schools as sds USING (school_id)
GROUP BY district_id, year, race WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: I don't want to have nulls, is there a way to do this without use rollup?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, to get the data on the same row you pretty much have to do this as a join:

```
select t.*, t2.cnt as TotalDistrictYear
from (SELECT sds.district_id,detail.year, detail.race, SUM(count) as cnt
      FROM school_data_race_ethnicity_raw as detail INNER JOIN
           school_data_schools as sds USING (school_id)
      GROUP BY district_id, year, race
     ) t join
    (SELECT sds.district_id,detail.year,SUM(count) as cnt
      FROM school_data_race_ethnicity_raw as detail INNER JOIN
           school_data_schools as sds USING (school_id)
      GROUP BY district_id, year
     ) t2
     on t.district_id = t2.district_id and
        t.year = t2.year
```